# how to replace one group of strings in one file with another group from another file

Tags: linux, file, awk, replace, sed

I have two files with content like below

`file1`

```
   pattern1something1end1
   pattern1something2end2
   pattern2something3end3
   pattern2something4end4
   pattern3something5end5
   pattern4something6end6
```

`file2`

```
   pattern0something7end7
   pattern1something8end8
   pattern1something9end9
   pattern2something10end10
   pattern2something11end11
   pattern2something12end12
   pattern3something13end13
   pattern4something14end14
```

Now I want `file1` to be changed with all lines starting from `pattern2` be replaced by all lines in `file2` which start with same `pattern2` in `linux` environment

so the final content in `file1` will be like below

```
   pattern1something1end1
   pattern1something2end2
   pattern2something10end10
   pattern2something11end11
   pattern2something12end12
   pattern3something5end5
   pattern4something6end6
```

Number of lines can be different for any pattern in both files and replacement shall be done with group of lines.

There will be only one group of lines starting with any pattern in both the files.

I would like to preferably use sed, but its not a constraint.

Similarly solution shall also work , if want to do similar exercise for `pattern1` or `pattern3`

Comment: have two files same number of lines, which start with `pat2`? if not, how do you handle them

Comment: @kent no, number of lines which start with `pattern2` can be different. to handle, group of lines in `file1` shall be replaced by a group of lines existing in `file2`

Comment: have you seen "how do you handle them" part?

Comment: @kent updated the question and comment also

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^pattern2/)a[++i]=$0;next}/^pattern2/{$0=a[++j]}7' f2 f1
```

The above awk one-liner will replace all `^pattern2` lines in file1 by matched lines in file2 .

you can use `awk -v pat="whatever" ...` then in code check the `pat` variable, so that you make it work for `pattern1, 2, 3,4...`

**Assume that the number of matched lines in file2 is >= number in file1**

#### Update according to the requirement change:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^pattern2/)a[++i]=$0;next}
     /^pattern2/{p=1;next}p{for(x in a)print a[x]}7' f2 f1
```

test:

```
kent$  head f1 f2    
==> f1 <==
pattern1something1end1
pattern1something2end2
pattern2something3end3
pattern2something4end4
pattern3something5end5

==> f2 <==
pattern0something7end7
pattern1something8end8
pattern1something9end9
pattern2something10end10
pattern2something11end11
pattern2something12end12
pattern3something13end13
pattern4something14end14

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^pattern2/)a[++i]=$0;next}/^pattern2/{p=1;next}p{for(x in a)print a[x]}7' f2 f1 
pattern1something1end1
pattern1something2end2
pattern2something10end10
pattern2something11end11
pattern2something12end12
pattern3something5end5
```

Comment: it is not working even when matched number of lines file2 are > number in file1 also

Comment: yes! because you updated the question. it worked for the 1st revision.

Comment: if i add last line in file f1 like below, it doesn't work propely

`pattern1something1end1`
`pattern1something2end2`
`pattern2something3end3`
`pattern2something4end4`
`pattern3something5end5`
**pattern4something6end6**

Comment: please check my comment for newly line addition

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{f=1}
      NR==FNR{if(/^pattern2/){
               if(a==""){a=$0;}else{a=a"\n"$0;}
             }next;}
     /pattern2/&&(f==1)
     {$0=a;f=0;}1' file2 file1
```

Test result below:

```
[ ~]$ awk 'BEGIN{f=1}NR==FNR{if(/^pattern2/){if(a==""){a=$0;}else{a=a"\n"$0;}}next}/pattern2/&&(f==1){$0=a;f=0}1' file2 file1
pattern1something1end1
pattern1something2end2
pattern2something10end10
pattern2something11end11
pattern2something12end12
pattern2something4end4
pattern3something5end5
[ ~]$
```

Comment: this line is extra *pattern2something4end4* in your output